# Adding frequency (count) of a point shapefile on an animated map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, time, animation, dynamic

I have a crime (point) data on a map which is animated via time slider using a 1-week-period.

I see all the points I added without a problem, I also added a dynamic text indicating the time period on each frame video shows.

I just would like to add in a text (I guess this should also be dynamic) the count of crimes (points) on each time period (week).

Answer (score 2):

Run the [Frequency tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Frequency/00080000001w000000/) to calculate frequency stat against each time period.  Then join each period table to the crime layer by the crime type, then link by dynamic text.