# Inserting accumulative attribute in dynamic text element based on Date field using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, layouts, timeslider

I've got a line feature class that contains Date field. I've made a layout view in order to display time animation of this feature class. I've managed to enable the time option in the layer and to create a Data Frame Time text in correspondence to the elapsed time.

I'm looking to enrich the layout by creating a dynamic text element of the feature class'  accumulated 'Shape_Length' field, according to the elapsed date\time - time elapsing > accumulated 'Shape_Length' gets bigger.

I've tried several ways to do it, but didn't succeed so far:

1. I've tried inspecting the Data Frame Time element Text syntax --- `<dyn type="dataFrame" name="Layers" property="time" emptyStr="[off]"/>` --- but couldn't figure how to change it to show the 'Shape_Length' field.

[image]

2. I've try an alternative approach: to create a date based graph. I've followed this [link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Visualizing_temporal_data_in_graphs/005z00000012000000/), and search quite along time in the Advanced Properties of the graph how to make it a time enabled and also how to make it accumulative. Didn't work as well.

I think the answer would be in connection to the [LayerTime](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000063000000) function.

Comment: What if you add an attribute to your line layer that is accumulated length for each segment and use that field? Sort of do the math beforehand rather than dynamically, so each record's accumleng would be shapelength plus previous accumleng and you create a dyn label out of that.

Comment: I thought of doing that but the problem is how to insert the new accumulated field into the layout. The only option of inserting time related text element in the conventional way (as far as I know...) is via the 'Data Frame Time' option, which I mentioned to be unsuccessful so far.
Do you had another idea how to use this new accumulated field in order to insert it?

Comment: Off hand, no. I guess I was thinking in terms of data driven pages rather than a time animation. There's a similar question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18216/ but no real detail in the answer. @artwork21 might be able to fill in some blanks. There are some other arcpy dynamic text questions here, but none that I think would address this challenge. I would have thought for sure something like this would have been asked before, but I can't find anything on it.

Comment: Using LayerTime would make this into an ArcPy question for which we need you to post a code snippet as the starting point.